# Searching through a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, `vector<Gate*> PI_Gates`, that can contain the characters 0, 1, D, D` (D Not), and X. Depending on the combination of characters in the vector, I will set an output to some value. Here is a example of what I have done so far:

```
if(GateType== GATE_NAND)
{   
    for(int i=0; i<PI_Gates.size(); i++)
    {

        if(PI_Gates[i]->getValue() == LOGIC_DBAR)
        {
            MyGate->setValue(LOGIC_D);
        }   
        else if(PI_Gates[i]->getValue() == LOGIC_ZERO)
        {
            MyGate->setValue(LOGIC_ONE);
        }
        else if(PI_Gates[i]->getValue() == LOGIC_X)
        {
            MyGate->setValue(LOGIC_X);
        }
        else if(PI_Gates[i]->getValue() == LOGIC_ONE)
        {
        }
}
```

This code is for analyzing a circuit at the gate level and outputting the results. For the cases where the input value is D, 0, or X, my output determined at that time since they will have logic priority. However, for this particular logic gate, if all my inputs are logic 1, then my output will be logic zero. Likewise, when all the inputs are logic D, my output will be logic D not. If the inputs are a combination of logic 1 and logic D, the output is still logic D not. As a result, I need to find a way to search through my vector and determine if my inputs are the following: all logic 1, all logic D, combination of logic 1 and D. And this is where I am stuck. I cannot come up with a good approach to this.

I guess im simpler terms, its like you have a vector that contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 and you want to check if all the values are either 4 or 5 and if they are, do some operation when you are done iterating through the vector. The solution may be something simple but I think i am over complicating it in my head.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend setting a temporary constant variable to the value of `getValue()` before the `if` ladder to prevent a bunch of calls.  The method only needs to be called once.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, better yet, replace it with the `switch`.

Comment: If you use an `enum` or single character type, then you could implement a `switch` statement instead of the `if-else` ladder.  With an `enum`, you could use an array of function pointers.

Comment: Better yet, place the valid values into an array of strings. If the string is in the array, then use `setValue(string)`.  No ladder required.

Comment: *its like you have a vector that contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 and you want to check if all the values are either 4 or 5 and if they are, do some operation when you are done*  --  If it boils down to this, then just calling `std::all_of` and acting on the return value is all you need to do.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yea. This was one change I planned on doing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So, would this be the correct code? `if(std::all_of(PI_Gates.begin(), PI_Gates.end(), 1||X)) return true;`? Because i need to check for both 1 and/or X. Or do i need two calls of `std::all_of()`?

Comment: @Noobgineer  Just get the first value in the vector.  Then if it's a 1 or an X, *then* you call `std::all_of` on that item.  `char item = PI_Gates[0]; if (item == '1' || item == 'X') { bool allSame = std::all_of(PI_Gates.begin(), PI_Gates.end(), item);}`  Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, a simple lookup would work:

```
const std::string valid_values[] = 
{ "0", "1", "D", "/D" /* D Not */, "X"};
//...
std::string * const end_ptr = &valid_values[sizeof(valid_values)];
const std::string value = PI_Gates[i]->getValue();
size_t position = find(&valid_values[0], // begin
                       end_ptr, // End
                       value);
if (position != end_ptr)
{
  // The gate name was found
  MyGate->setValue(value);
}
```

If you want more versatility, you could use a `std::map<string, function pointer>` and associate functions with gate names.  A table of structures containing the gate name and function pointer would work too.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this solution as i cannot determine how to use it for my scenario. I am not trying to lookup the names of the gates. `MyGate` is the actual gate that i am analyzing and i want to determine the output based on the input. However, this has to be generalized for an n-input gate. As a result, if i have a gate with 15 inputs, i cannot analyze it with the same code that is specific for a 2 input gate. So my solution was to use corner-cases per say but this is where I get stuck on the best approach to determine if my gate's inputs are all 1's or X's or a combination of both.

Comment: I suggest using a table of function pointers (or an `std::map`).  The idea is that you lookup in a table the input value and execute the function pointer associated with the input.  With this generic pattern, you could define an "Inputs" class which will execute function pointers based on a given input.  But that is probably best another question.

Comment: Modelling gates and circuits is definitely too broad for a StackOverflow question.  I recommend using `enum` for the data type that is passed to inputs and outputs.  This allows for the use of a `switch` statement and other efficient data structures.